# Should multilingual support be handled by React or Node?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, multilingual, mern

I am creating a project's backend using NodeJS, And frontend will be handled by React (Teammate). But our question is where do we handle multilingual support (frontend/backend) and how?

Comment: multilingual should be handled on both sides front/back, for some static text like button text and placeholder should be handled on the react and API responses from the backend by getting language form the req headers

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.